# underscore.js template from an HTML element

Tags: javascript, templates, underscore.js

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#template {
    display: none;
}
</style>
<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/underscore-min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="template">
        <div id="event">
            <button><%= title %></button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <button id="cmd_create_event" name="cmd_create_event" type="button">Create
        a new `EventModel`</button>

    <div id="div_event_list"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#cmd_create_event").click(function() {
                var template = $("div#template div#event").children().html();
                var compiled = _.template(template);
                $("#div_event_list").html(compiled({
                    title : "New Event Title"
                }));
            });
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

The above would work perfectly if the `html()` call wouldn't return this: `&lt;%= title %&gt;`

I want it to return **exactly** `<button><%= title %></button>`, as I wrote it in the HTML, so I can use it for templating with underscore.

How?

Alternatively, is there any better way? Without extra dependency (jquery/underscore only). Without (too much) extra code.

Comment: It's funny how you find an answer almost right after you ask a question, even if you spent hours on it. There is an option to `_.templateSettings()` which will `change Underscore's template settings to use different symbols to set off interpolated code`. However, I'm still interested in hearing your opinions.

Comment: Well storing your templates in parsed HTML elements is liable to give you problems no matter what you do with the Underscore settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of storing your template source in a `<div>`, put it in an unevaluated `<script>` block:

```
<script type='text/template' id='template'>
  <button><%= title %></button>
</script>
```

When you fetch the contents of that with `.html()`, you'll get the contents back exactly as they look. That "type" value is made-up (by me); you can use anything *except* a real JavaScript type, and the browser will just ignore it completely. It will however include it in the DOM and allow you to fetch its contents. Since the contents are not expected to be HTML, it won't care about the HTML metacharacters.

The conversion of your template markers to `&lt;` and '>' is being done by the browser because that's really what you've fed it: unescaped HTML metacharacters are really not allowed, but the browser recognizes that that's what the `<%` and `%>` are so it interprets them that way.

Comment: Excellent answer and insights. Thank you!

Comment: This is doubly true when you have `<div id="event">` in the template.